# Simple ReadProcessMemory not working

Tags: c++, readprocessmemory

I googled a bit but can't seem to make this work.

```
privileges();
int pid = getPid("test.exe");
cout << "Process ID :" << pid << endl;

const char* prename;
HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ , FALSE, pid);
if (pHandle)
{
    cout << "Handle Open Success" << endl;
    //SIZE_T bytesRead;
    if (ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (void*)0x013831BC, &prename, strlen(prename), NULL))
    {
        cout << "Read Success" << endl;
        cout << prename << endl;
    }

    else
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;

}
return 0;
```

It prints "Read Success" but does not print the variable just blank. The address(address of a string in another process) I got is from ollydbg and verified it using a function as well.

I also wanted to replace the string using writeprocessmemory but before i get to that i needed to make sure reading is correct.

Any idea?

Comment: Looks like you're using uninitialized memory. Try changing `const char *prename` to `char prename[500]`, where 500 is some number that's definitely large enough to hold the whole string, and `strlen(prename)` to `sizeof(prename)`

Comment: Perfect ! Now trying with writing but no effect                                                char nVal[8] = "testing"
LPVOID lpRemoteAddress =VirtualAllocEx(pHandle, 0, 4096, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, lpRemoteAddress, &nVal, sizeof(nVal), NULL)

Comment: What result are you expecting? You're allocating new memory and writing to it, not overwriting any existing data.

Comment: I am trying to replace string at that address to "testing" .

Comment: Then just use the same address (`(void*)0x013831BC`) to write the new string instead of allocating `lpRemoteAddress`. You may also need to use `VirtualProtectEx` if the string is in read-only memory.

Comment: Perfect ! Fixed Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```cpp
const char* prename;

ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (void*)0x013831BC, &prename, strlen(prename), NULL)
```

Your char pointer is not initialized and neither is the random memory it points to.  When you call strlen on it, it's trying to get the length of a random memory location.

Secondly you're using the address of the pointer `&prename`, that's the address of the pointer not the char array it should point to.

To fix do it like this:

```
char prename[100];

ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (void*)0x013831BC, &prename, sizeof(prename), NULL)
```

sizeof() will return 100, so you will be reading 100 bytes of memory